# Javascript for loop for exact iterations

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a for loop to push a random number of unique elements from a big array into another small array. I want exact number of elements to be pushed into that small array.

```
$scope.word_pair = [
    {'word':'Carla', 'pair':'Lion'},
    {'word':'Sophie', 'pair':'Lotta'},
    {'word':'Jannes', 'pair':'Stubbi'},
    {'word':'Martin', 'pair':'Wolle'},
    {'word':'Flo', 'pair':'Ign'},
    {'word':'Rere', 'pair':'Rose'},
    {'word':'Jean', 'pair':'Tamara'},
    {'word':'Memo', 'pair':'Elk'},
    {'word':'Nila', 'pair':'Naph'}
];

/* To select limited random items to display */
var displayCount = 3 //count should change at each level
$scope.randomWord_pair = []
var numbers = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= displayCount; i++) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    if (numbers.indexOf(randomNumber) == -1) {
        numbers.push(randomNumber);
        $scope.randomWord_pair.push($scope.word_pair[randomNumber])
    }
}
```

Here `displayCount` decides how many (exact) number of elements I want in my `randomWord_pair` array. However, sometimes it gives me other than 3 elements in `randomWord_pair` array.

How can I fix it?

Comment: *"Code snippet is updated with the suggestion in answer"* No, that's not how SO works. You don't fold answers into the question, it makes the answers look like nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons for that:

1. You're looping too much. `i = 0; i <= displayCount; i++` will give you **four** iterations for `displayCount = 3`, not three: `i` will be 0, then 1, then 2, and then 3.
2. You're not looping enough. :-) You're only pushing a number if you don't find it, meaning you don't always push a number for a loop iteration.

Just use

```
while ($scope.randomWord_pair.length < displayCount)
```

---

You've said in a comment that the code is also missing out some word pairs, and you've added the code for `$scope.word_pairs`.

`$scope.word_pairs` has nine entries (indexes 0 through 8 inclusive), but your random number code:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
```

...will only ever give you values from 0 to 3 (inclusive). If you want all nine possible indexes into `word_pairs`, you want:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.word_pairs.length);
// -------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: However,  here is one problem: while ($scope.randomWord_pair.length < displayCount) generates random numbers from 3, I want to generate it from $scope.word_pair which has 9 elements:: so any 3 unique random numbers from 9

Comment: @Nitish: No it doesn't. It loops until you've pushed three items onto the array. Nothing random there at all.

Comment: Let me rephrase what I want to say!: Right now I get 3 elements at random from first four elements of $scope.word_pair, it do not consider all 9 elements, so Ign , Ros, Tamara never appears! I updated code snippet in the question.

Comment: @Nitish: If I understand you correctly, that's completely unrelated. If you want a random number between 0 and 8 (to pick from `word_pair`), `Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)` is obviously not going to do that, as you'll get a number between 0 and 3. You want `Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.word_pair.length)`

Comment: Great! I didn't realize what that  '* 4' was doing. It solved the problem! Thank you so much for pointing out two major mistakes.